# please help me with this logic based question.what is the missing block?

Tags: pattern, dice

Please complete the figure with one of 9 blocks below.

[image]

Comment: Hi!  This looks like a puzzle you've found elsewhere, rather than one you made yourself - if so, please could you [edit] the question to add attribution and credit the source?  (i.e. the name of the Book/Website and the Author)

Answer (score 5):

**Answer:**

> Block 4 (3 pipped die). If you combine any other two die in a strait line horizontally or vertically, you produce the third die in the line. Pips cancel each other out if they overlap.